# Codeigniter 4 routing seems not working properly

Tags: routes, codeigniter-4

In Routes.php I configured most routing rules:

```
...
$routes->get('{locale}/contenuto/(:any)', 'Contenuto::index/$1');
$routes->get('contenuto/(:any)', 'Contenuto::index/$1');
$routes->get('{locale}/cerca', 'Cerca::index/$1');
$routes->get('cerca', 'Cerca::index/$1');
...
```

These URLs are working:

```
http://localhost:8080/it/cerca
http://localhost:8080/it/contenuto/content_slug
http://localhost:8080/contenuto/content_slug
```

and correct views are displayed.
This rule doesn't work:

```
http://localhost:8080/cerca
```

and redirect to default URL.
There are the Contenuto controller and the Cerca controller that are working in a proper way.
Is there a reason because it doesn't work?
Is there a way to understand why it doesn't work?

Comment: And what happens if you change $routes->get('cerca', 'Cerca::index/$1'); to $routes->get('cerca', 'Cerca::index');

Comment: It doesn't work...

Comment: Do you have a default set for your input variable for Cerca::index. I.E function index($variable = '') or what ever the default language is.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't write the complete problem: in routes rules I had also $routes->get('{locale}', 'Home::index'); and //localhost:8080/cerca (I don't know why) goes in this rule.

Comment: So you are all sorted out then?

Comment: Languages are 'it' and 'en', the default language is 'it'.